# With R.drawable.test, can test be changed using a for loop?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to make it so that if a char is '1' then a drawable image of 1 will be shown. If the char is '2' then a 2 image will display.

[This will 100% work but it's inefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjAFt.png)

[These two are the general idea, but it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od7rV.png)

Comment: Improve your question looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the used `if`s and cleanup the code of the first example. Then you do not have to duplicate the if statements (have a look at the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

However, you still need a separate drawable for every number:

```kotlin
val mapping = mapOf(
   "1" to R.drawable.rating1,
   "2" to R.drawable.rating2,
   "3" to R.drawable.rating3,
   "4" to R.drawable.rating4,
   ...
   "10" to R.drawable.rating10,
)

val number = parseItem.getImageUrl().charAt(34)
val drawableId = mapping[number]

Picasso
    .get()
    .load(drawableUrl)
    .fit()
    .centerInside()
    .into(holder.imageView)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use`"R.drawable.rating"+String.valueOf(i)+".png"`

Instead of `"R.drawable.rating1.png"` in your second attempt

Or just use a switch statement instead.

Let me know if you want switch statement explained